# What does the star/asterisk next to a technology mean?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-2

When I trade with other races, sometimes there is a little star (*) next to a technology. This happened both with my technologies and theirs.

Unfortunately as with many things in GalCiv 2, it is nowhere explained in the GUI.

What does the star mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After intensive search I finally found [this thread](http://forums.galciv2.com/381173) which reveals that

> The asterisks mark techs that are unique to the civ but can be traded.

I guess that makes sense, Xeno Slavery is something that can only be researched by the Drengin according to the [GalCiv2 wiki](http://galciv.wikia.com/wiki/TA_Technology):

> The Drengin Tech Tree replaces Xeno Engineering with Xeno Slavery.

So it appears that through trade you can acquire technology that would be unavailable through normal research.